# How to fix error of "libomp.dylib cannot be found" while trying to importing PyCaret

Tags: python, apple-m1, pycaret

I have a Macbook M1 pro. When I was trying to import pycaret in python, I got this error. After hours of searching, I applied all solutions but none of them solved my problem.
I tried to install libomp with "brew install libomp" but it didn't work. I also tried to install it with x86_64 brew thinking that may be worked, but did not.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the issue with downloading libomp.dylib directly and locate it where it is saying in the error.
Here are the steps you may follow:

1. You can download libomp.dylib from here. Be aware of choosing your own versions.

$curl -O https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/openmp-13.0.0-darwin21-Release.tar.gz

2. Open and locate the files where it is needed to be.

$sudo tar fvxz openmp-12.0.1-darwin20-Release.tar.gz -C /

3. You may also check your versioning.

$codesign -d -vv libomp.dylib

Then, you are good to use PyCaret in your Macbook M1 pro.